# How can I turn on my iPhone's Developer mode when it keeps turning off after the required restart

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to enable developer mode.

I go to Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Developer Mode.

When I flick the toggle to on, it prompts me to restart, I tap the Restart option and my phone restarts.

Once it's back on, I get prompted to type my PIN, I do and I'm back to the home page and developer mode is still off. This is where I think something is wrong, because in some instructions I read that there is supposed to be a popup asking me to confirm enabling developer mode, but I don't see it.

My phone is an iPhone SE 3rd gen running on iOS 17.3.1, I have tried to update to 17.4, but I get a message saying "Unable to Verify Update, iOS 17.4 is temporarily unavailable. Try again later.", so I'm gonna try again later, but for now I can't update.

What can I do?

My goal is to be able to run an in-development app that comes from App Center, when I try to launch it, it says I need to enable developer mode to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to enable it by accident!

I put an old sim card that doesn't work anymore and it showed me a new screen about activating the phone and returning an error because the phone is locked to some carrier. I removed the sim card and I tried activating developer mode again, and it worked...